# How-to configure IConfigurationRoot and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext for dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions app. I would like my code to be able to access settings configured for the Azure Functions app. I am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection for dependency injection.

To access configuration data, I am using this code:

```
[FunctionName("MyEndpoint")]
public static Task<IActionResult> MyFuncAsync(ExecutionContext context)
        {
 IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
}
```

This works great in the function itself. However, I would like to be able to injection IConfigurationRoot into my classes. I can't figure out how set up the dependency injection container so that it will create the IConfigurationRoot class using the execution context injected into the Azure function method. I'd like to be able to create a class like this:

```
public class MyWorkerClass(IConfigurationRoot config) 
{
...
}
```

Comment: use a static constructor where you set up all you configuration and service collection. Then use them in the function itself.

Comment: Ideally you should not be injecting the configuration root into anything. It may indicate a deeper issue with your design and separation of concerns.

Comment: @Nkosi I don't see a design issue with this. If you care to explain further I'm willing to listen. I have interfaces that I use within all my applications to pull settings. I implement concrete classes based on the application enviornment - Asp.Net, WinForms, Azure Functions. My interfaces allow me to get to configuration data without worrying about the specifics of that environment. My code is reusable and portable. In this case, my concrete class is dependent on ExecutionContext.

Comment: It is slightly different for Azure Functions because their static nature does not lend well for DI. As for the design issue I mentioned,`IConfigurationRoot` though an interface, is an implementation concern specific to .net core.

Comment: Can you provide more context about the function to be invoked and how the dependent classes  are used/invoked.

Comment: @Nkosi after reviewing Microsoft doc, I find I am following the same concept for configuration. See this link and search for IConfiguration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: It's a bit late, but check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection . Azure functions now supports dependency injection. You can register your services in startup class, and they get injected into constructors. Also, you can now make your function non-static (if that goes well with your existing design).